# Replace environment variable in docker-compose.yml with command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I need to set a env variable in my docker-compose.yml with the output of a console command.

I tried this:

```
environment:
    - JWT_PASSPHRASE=$$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32)
```

When running `echo ${JWT_PASSPHRASE}` in the container then, it outputs `date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32`.

I also tried surrounding the command with backticks, but that also doesn't work.

Can anyone help?